# ASP.NET Core Action Filter to return specific partial view if model is null

Tags: asp.net-core, action-filter

I have an Action which returns a partial view with a model but I have to check if the model is null...

Now I use the following code to check this and return a different partial view if the model is null

```
if (model == null)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/PartialViews/_frmSideBarWindowInfo.cshtml", new SideBarWindowInfo { Nachricht = "Der Datensatz kann nicht angezeigt werden, da er gelöscht wurde!" });
}
```

But instead of adding this to every Action which return a partial view I want to write an ActionFilter and add the ActionFilterAttribute to the necessary Actions.

My problem is which kind of Actionfilter is the best for the ResultFilter? And how to change the partial view and model in this filter?

Answer (score 0):

Filters seem like overkill for something like this. You could just make an extension method and keep this really simple.

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static PartialViewResult SideBar(this Controller controller, object model)
    {
        return SideBar(null, model);
    }

    public static PartialViewResult SideBar(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return controller.PartialView("~/Views/Shared/PartialViews/_frmSideBarWindowInfo.cshtml", 
                new SideBarWindowInfo 
                { 
                    Nachricht = "Der Datensatz kann nicht angezeigt werden, da er gelöscht wurde!" 
                });
        }

        return controller.PartialView(viewName, model);
    }
}
```

Then import the namespace where you put `ControllerExtensions` in your controller, and call this from your action methods instead of `PartialView`:

```
return SideBar(model); // instead of PartialView(model);
```

or

```
return SideBar("SomeView", model); // instead of PartialView("SomeView", model);
```

Comment: do you mean use `using Gpdb.Extensions;` and then call it like:

`return ControllerExtensions.SideBarWindow(this, "~/Areas/Mitglied/Views/Fachgruppenzugehoerig/_frmFachgruppenzugehoerigEdit.cshtml", model);`

Comment: You could do that, but normally you call an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) on the instance it extends  as in my example (in this case `Controller`). If you put `using Gpdb.Extensions` at the top of the controller type `this.` in an action method, you should be able to see the `SideBarWindow` method in Intellisense. If not, you have not setup your extension method correctly. Note extension methods must be defined in a static class.

Comment: OK it works:

`return this.SideBarWindow("~/Areas/Mitglied/Views/Fachgruppenzugehoerig/_frmFachgruppenzugehoerigEdit.cshtml", model);`